# Why did Heidegger chose to delay the publications of his Beiträge zur Philosophie?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, heidegger, german-philosophy

Heidegger's Beiträge (Contributions to philosophy) were published with other writings in 1989, 50 years after their completion, as per Heidegger wish. Do we have any indication from Heidegger, veiled or unveiled, in private correspondences or in public writings, as to why it was delayed?

Comment: I suspect some political reasons were in play, given Heidegger's affiliation with the Nazi party and its aftermath we all know. Heidegger did a half critique of his joining the Nazi party based on his Dasein philosophy but I find it simply as apologetic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very clear and motivated explanation can be found in the editor's afterword of the Beiträge. Heidegger wanted the prerequisite texts of the GA to be published before the unpublished works, to which the Beiträge belong. Here is the relevant excerpt:

> Daß dieses wegeröffnende große Manuskript nicht etwa
> gleich zu Beginn, sondern erst vierzehn Jahre nach dem Beginn
> der Gesamtausgabe erscheint, hat seinen Grund in einer von Heidegger für die Herausgabe seiner Gesamtausgabe gegebenen
> und ihm besonders wichtigen Anweisung. Ihr zufolge
> durfte mit der Veröffentlichung der für die III. und IV. Abteilung
> vorgesehenen Schriften erst dann begonnen werden, wenn
> die Vorlesungen der II. Abteilung herausgegeben sind. Diese
> Entscheidung erläuterte er durch die Bemerkung, daß Kenntnis
> und aneignendes Studium der Vorlesungstexte eine notwendige
> Voraussetzung seien für das Verständnis der unveröffentlichten
> Schriften, insbesondere aus den dreißiger Jahren und
> der ersten Hälfte der vierziger Jahre.

And the translation from Richard Rojcewicz and Daniela Vallega-Neu:

> This crucial text opens the way and yet was not published to inaugurate
> the Gesamtausgabe but instead is only appearing now, fourteen
> years after the first volumes in the series. The reason lies in one of
> Heidegger's directives for the publication of the Gesamtausgabe, a directive
> that was of particular importance to him. It stipulated that
> publication of the writings assigned to divisions III and IV could
> commence only after the lecture courses of divisions II were brought
> out. Heidegger explained this decision by remarking that knowledge
> and appropriating study of the lecture texts were necessary prerequisites
> for understanding the unpublished writings, especially those
> from the 1930s and the first half of the 1940s.

Comment: The editor also gives some precision about the nature of those prerequisites: "Of the lecture courses from the 1930s, whose study is necessarily
demanded for a comprehension of Contributions to Philosophy, the most
prominent of all is the one from the winter semester 1937-38, Basic
Questions of Philosophy: Selected 'Problems' of 'Logic'."

Answer (score 0):

According to the SEP article on Heidegger which has a section on the *Contributions*, they suggest that Heidegger might have been thinking that his later works were required as interpretive commentary to understand what he was saying in this earlier work. As a reputable and scholarly source, had there been any private or public correspondance available as to why Heidegger wished for such a late publication, I would have expected the SEP to refer to it. So I would suggest, no, there isn't any such secret missive from Heidegger.

They also note that this work has recieved mixed reviews from Heideggerean scholars with Poggeler stating its where Heideggers complete thought is captured. But other scholars had less charitable things to say with Sheehan stating:

> it is a needlessly difficult text, obsessively repetitious, badly in need of an editor.

Whilst Schurman complains:

> At times one might think one is reading a piece of Heideggerian plaigarism, so encumbered it is with ellipses and asserotic monoliths.

The "asserotic monoliths" is interesting as traditionally philosophers engaged in *argument* rather than *assertion*; or rather, they asserted something only after it had been argued for ...

And actually, I have noticed these "asserotic monoliths" and was puzzled somewhat that no-one noticed that one assertian was being piled on top of another without a whit of argument to cement them together. So I'm glad to see someone complain about them.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, unfortunately the SEP article was written in 2011 while the black notebooks were only published around 2014-2015. As for the SEP argument that later works were required to understand the Contributions, I don't find it so convincing : his thinking really evolved in those 50 years and, on the contrary, the Contributions stand as the missing piece between Sein und Zeit and its second period.

Comment: @Johan: The SEP states the *Contributions to Philosophy* were published in 1989 in German and in English in 1999. The SEP article was written well after its publication and the SEP already concur that these notes were written during his Turn. What exactly do the black notebooks add here to this?

Comment: @Johan: Personally, I'd suggest that Heidegger knew that this work was unpolished and kept it for his own use whilst he developed the ideas contained within it. This explains its uneveness and its "repetition" that scholars who aren't so invested in Heidegger spotted.

Comment: @johan: And also this is likely why he didn't particularly want it published.

Comment: I was referring to the personal notebooks of Heidegger which were published as the Black Notebooks ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Notebooks)) way after the Contributions. As for its unevenness I really don't think it can't be seen as an unpolishedness.

Comment: They have to do with my question and your answer : we can't say that "there isn't any such secret missive from Heidegger" by referring to the SEP as the article was written before the publications of those Notebooks. There may be some indications in those notebooks.

Comment: @Johan: Yes, I know about the notebooks, they were a famous publishing event in philosophy a few years ago and kicked up quite a fuss about the anti-semitism at the heart of Heidegger's thought, a I claim I can full well believe and which he inherited from Nietzsche. In his *Contributions* he talks about the essential "Jewishness of Bolshevism". I think the SEP are correct to characterise them as unpolished as I had a brief look at it just now. The occasional passage where his thought coheres stands out by its lucidity but all too often it just sprawls. Its clear to me that its a place ...

Comment: @Johan: ... where he was working out his philosophy. Philosophy doesn't just drop out of the sky into a man's mind fully formed ...

Comment: @Johan: There are good reasons as to why Heidegger joined the Nazi Party - it has a great deal to do with Nietschzes advocacy of the Jews instilling "a slave revolt in morals". I mention this because so few Nietzschean scholars, if any, bother their conscience about this. And he lead Heidegger astray ...